# Type assertions

Tags: typescript

Кто ни будь может на пальцах объяснить с нормальными примерами, что такое *assertions* в typescript и где это применяется. В документации этому  вопросу, уделяется несколько строк с не понятными примерами.

Вот пример:

```
let someValue: any = "this is a string";

let strLength: number = (someValue as string).length;
```

Не понятно что вообще в этом коде происходит.

Comment: добавь в вопрос цитату из документации и пример, который непонятен

Comment: пример плохой, если ты в нем уберешь _as string_ ничего не поменяется. Добавь ссылку на документацию, которую ты читаешь

Comment: замени в своем примере `any` на `{}` и сразу увидишь разницу и смысл применения `as string`

Comment: ссылка на документацию, раздел Type assertions https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html вот я не пойму тему, что хотели этим примером показать.

Answer (score 5):

В [документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) есть следующее:

> *Type assertions* – это возможность сказать компилятору "Доверься мне, я знаю что делаю". *Type assertion* похож на каст в других языках программирования, но не делает каких-либо специальных проверок или преобразований. Он никак не влияет на время выполнения и добавляется **только** для компилятора. *TypeScript* надеется, что ты уже сделал все проверки, которые нужны.

Далее приводится пример:

```
let someValue: any = "this is a string";

let strLength: number = (someValue as string).length;
```

Из-за `any` пример возможно не очень удачен, так как для этого типа нет проверок, какие свойства у него вызываются, и можно вызвать любое свойство, и компилятор не укажет на ошибку, с другой стороны, ide не подскажет, что у *someValue* есть такое свойство, как `length`.

В случае же с *type assertions*, автодополнение начнет работать.

Более наглядным пример может стать, если заменить `any`, на `{}`. В этом случае

```
let someValue: {} = "this is a string";
```

При попытке вызвать `someValue.length` компилятор покажет ошибку

> Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'

И в этом случае использование *type assertions* становится понятнее: мы знаем, что в данной переменной будет строка, у которой есть свойство `length` и подсказываем об этом компилятору:

```
(someValue as string).length
```

или

```
(<string>someValue).length
```

В этом случае компилятор верит, что эта переменная имеет строковое значение, а значит у нее можно взять свойство `length`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ сейчас стало понятно, при переводе меня смутила это строка "Type assertion это как приведение к типу в других языках", поэтому и не понял приведенный пример.

Comment: Подскажите, а как в таком случае делается реальное приведение типов? Неужели нужно ручками пройтись по всему объекту и убедится, что все поля на месте, а потом если все ок сделать какой-нибудь Object.Assing? Могу отдельный вопрос запилить, вроде, не видел, что бы тут задовалось.

Comment: @iluxa1810, никак, оно не нужно.