# Как правильно использовать Array.filter с typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, типы-данных

Мне нужно удалить все boolean значения из массива, и оставить только строки(массива состоит из boolean и string), хочу сделать это методом filter,
но typeScript выдаёт ошибку, что init может быть как boolean, так и string. Т.е. он не понимает, что после filter останется только string.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать эту операцию правильно, что бы не было ошибок ts?**

```
let init: (string | boolean)[] = ['fsdfd', 'fsdfsd', false]
let b: string[] = init.filter(item=> typeof item === 'string')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как в данном случае в результате точно будет массив строк, можно прозрачно намекнуть компилятору об этом с помощью ["приведения"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (подробнее можно посмотреть в ответе на вопрос про [Type assertions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659707/186999))

```
let init: (string | boolean)[] = ['fsdfd', 'fsdfsd', false]
let b: string[] = <string[]>init.filter(item=> typeof item === 'string')
```

[**Пример**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20init%3A%20(string%20%7C%20boolean)%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B'fsdfd'%2C%20'fsdfsd'%2C%20false%5D%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%3Cstring%5B%5D%3Einit.filter(item%3D%3E%20typeof%20item%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string'))