# ERROR TypeError: value.buildHierarchy is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Не могу понять, где у меня ошибка...

Вот класс с методом:

```
export class Category extends ModelObject {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  parent: Category;

  buildHierarchy(): string {
    let result: string = "";
    let currentCategory: Category = this;

    while (currentCategory.parent != null) {
      result = `${currentCategory.name}${result != null?'->':''}${result}`;
      currentCategory = currentCategory.parent;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь пройти по массиву этих объектов и вызвать метод:

```
result => {
      let categories = <Category[]>result;
      categories.forEach(value => {
        this.categories.setValue(value.buildHierarchy(), value);
      }
```

и ловлю ошибку на вызове метода value.buildHierarchy().

В чем косяк? Все норм компилиться и IDE ничего не подсвечвает, но Chrome кидает ошибку ERROR TypeError: value.buildHierarchy is not a function.

**UPD**

Посмотрел **proto** и не увидел там функции, однако, если создать объект руками, то там есть функция. Получается, что TS при приведении типов создает неполноценные объекты?

Comment: Запись вида `<Category[]>result` не создает вам объекты класса `Category`. Она просто приводит их к этому типу. Для создания объекта класса - надо их создавать)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, как-то не очевидно=(

Comment: Да, не совсем очевидно. Просто надо держать в голове, что TS - это всего лишь примочка для статической типизации по сути. Ничего сверх этого он не делает (ну кроме трансляции в js, естественно).

Comment: _Она просто приводит их к этому типу._ - не, [даже не приводит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659707/186999) :-)

Comment: @Grundy получается, что если я хочу реальный объект, то мне нужно через assign создавать из фиктивного объекта настоящий?

Comment: нет, если тебе нужен объект класса, ты должен использовать конструктор

Comment: @Grundy а assign- это плохим тоном считается и правильнее иметь конструктор, который на вход принимает any, а внутри выполняются првоерки или есть подводные камни?

Comment: @iluxa1810, нет, и assign не плохой тон, и конструктор принимающий any - не нужен.

Comment: @Grundy а, как тогда? Можно пример?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91398/discussion-between-grundy-and-iluxa1810).