# Как продублировать методы в HtmlElement, или Type Assertion в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ооп

Изучаю ООП в JavaScript
Хочу создать создать свой класс на основе базового, продублировать метод этого класса, и потом сделать приведение типов ("type assertion")

```
class Rabbit extends HTMLElement{
    myQuerySelector = this.querySelector()
}
elOne = document.querySelector('div');
elSecond = (el as Rabbit).myQuerySelector('span');
```

Этот код не работает, ибо насколько я понял - в JavaScript нет оператора "as". Он есть в TypeScript.
Можно ли такую задачу решить на чистом JavaScript ?

И вопрос из этой же серии: можно ли модифицировать сам класс HtmlElement ?
Другими словами, чтобы в классе HtmlElement появился метод myQuerySelector ?

Comment: Чисто для разработки я использую JSDoc, которые очень хорошо поддерживаются в WebStorm

Comment: _type assertion_ - не нужен. Ты у любого объекта можешь попытаться вызвать любой метод.

Comment: более того, `as` в тайпскрипте [не делает приведения типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659707/186999), поэтому просто так в объекте не появятся нужные тебе методы

Comment: На счёт мутирования базовых классов - это наверно одно из самых опасных вещей, чем ты можешь заняться)) Лучше наслодавться и добавлять что тебе надо. Мы так делам в Веб Компонентах, очень удобно и ничего не ломается

Comment: Я изучаю ООП в рамках решения одной конкретной задачи)) Один сайт сделал spoofing всех этих методов. И когда я просто в консоли пишу el.querySelector('....') - сайт сразу видит что работает робот. При этом я могу делать любые действия в момент загрузки страницы, но до того как загрузились скрипты сайта. Т.е. я могу сделать свои подмены. И вот для этого мне нужно сделать свою подмену метода htmElement.querySelector и htmElement.dispatchEvent

Comment: @AlexeyD, а что за задача-то?

Comment: Выше отредактировал

Comment: Например, сайт заспуфил document.querySelector. Но я в момент загрузки делаю вот так:  byselector = document.querySelector.bind(document);
byselectorAll = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);  И потом работаю уже с byselector. Но HtmlElemnt.querySelector - это метод объекта, и как его продублировать - не понимаю

Comment: Если тебе нужно изменить методы из `htmElement` - причем тут наследование из вопроса?

Comment: Не изменить методы htmlElemnt. А продублировать их, сохранить в первозданном виде) А наследование мне нужно было именно для их сохранения. Т.е. я делаю свой класс на основе базового, и потом делаю (el as MyClass).myQuerySelector() ...

Comment: document.querySelector - это фактически отдельная функция. А HTMLElemnt.querySelector - это метод, применяющийся к самому объекту. В этом и проблема

Comment: подход с наследованием - не работает, даже на уровне идеи: потом что наследуемые свойства/методы точно также бы поменялись. И даже если работал `as` как ты хотел - ты бы все равно вызвал уже измененный метод.

Comment: `document.querySelector` и `HTMLElemnt.querySelector` - это разные методы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136545/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexeyd).